# How to encrypt/decrypt sensitive properties in a Tomcat web application

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, jdbc, tomcat9

I'm working on moving a java web application from development to pre-production. As part of that process, there are some fields in the tomcat 'application.properties' file like the database password and API tokens that need to be encrypted. I'm struggling to find a secure way to do this. I was originally planning on using [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/), but from what I can tell, that library hasn't seen a substantial update in several years. I'm not sure what the alternatives are. The best I can come up with is querying a stored private key variable from gitlab, but I would still need to figure out how to actually do the encryption/decription.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Some notes about the limitations I'm working with:

- The application is compiled as a WAR and then copied to the webapps directory of the tomcat server.
- Tomcat is being started/stopped as a service using a systemctl command.
- Eventually, the deployment will be done as part of a CI pipline, but for now I need to be able to build and deploy manually from a local environment.

Comment: Where are you going to host your app? The large cloud providers all offer managed secret handling like AWS Secrets Manager.

Comment: @RancidCrab The application will be running in an Ubuntu environment hosted in AWS. Storing a secret isn't the problem, I need to figure out how to access that data in the context of my application.

Comment: Call the Java impl of the AWS Secrets Manager API https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/secretsmanager/SecretsManagerClient.html#getSecretValue(software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.model.GetSecretValueRequest)

Comment: You may add more context and limitations. `Jasyp` is safe and good enough for most of the cases. Then the question is - where/how do you store and configure the decryption key. usually it has to be part of the environment parameters (variable, ...). . When using an external service (AWS SecretManager, Azure KeyVault, ...)  you need to store thes service credentials somewhere too.. (except when running on the cloud, when a runtime role could be used).

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate more, the answer given by Richard is 100% valid, and not only we can use AWS Secret Manager to secure sensitive data but also vaults like HashiCorp, or if budget/requirement permits we can use a solution based on HSM (Hardware security module) which could be overkill.

Limitations given by you are not a problem cause this is the standard procedure for deployment of application WAR.

But if you have decided that you want to encrypt the Sensitive data what you can do is.

Encrypt the sensitive data using Some encryption algorithm and save the actual key in AWS secret manager itself. Post deployment of the application when you have access to your AWS secrets manager from your code, you can always ask for an encryption key from the secrets manager and decrypt your data on the fly.

This again has one issue where in the above operation we are assuming our AWS secret credentials are safe in the first place. (standard chicken and egg problem)

As you can see there's no one solution fits all scenario. One needs to make sure that we follow all the standards related to maintaining sensitive data at every level. (key rotation, monitoring, service authorization, auditing ...the list goes on)

Hope this helps. Thanks.